# MySQL data sort

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table that has four columns: `id`, `item_number`, `feature`, `value`.

The table looks like this and has about 5 million entries.

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ item_number ║ feature ║ value ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 234         ║ 5       ║ 15    ║
║ 2  ║ 234         ║ 3       ║ 256   ║
║ 3  ║ 453         ║ 5       ║ 14    ║
║ 4  ║ 453         ║ 4       ║ 12    ║
║ 5  ║ 453         ║ 7       ║ 332   ║
║ 6  ║ 17          ║ 5       ║ 88    ║
║ 7  ║ 17          ║ 9       ║ 13.86 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

How can I sort the table so that I can get the `item_numbers` in descending order based on the feature value?

I am also selecting other feature numbers with their values but I only want to sort by feature number 5.

Comment: What do you mean by _item_numbers in descending order based on the feature value_ (this ___based___ part)?

Comment: @suslov I am looking for 17, 234, 453 as the result, as 17 has the highest value of 88 for the feature 5

Comment: Update OP with the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, add

`order by item_number desc`

If you are trying to query based on a specific feature, so only receive one set of data for a feature at at time, add

`where feature = 'feature'`

where "feature" is the feature value you want to search for. If you are looking to provide all features but sort them, you can add

`order by feature, item_number desc`

and you will be give all features in ascending order and together (grouped) then the items_number(s) in descending order

EDIT::
Sounds like from your latest comment, this may be your solution:

```
SELECT item_number FROM table WHERE feature = '5' ORDER BY value DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `order by` with `desc` and `where` clauses:

```
select `item_numbers`
from `tbl`
where `feature` = 5
order by `value` desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do order  by  first with  feature and then  with item_numbers

```
select * from `table` order by `feature`, `item_numbers` desc
```